# Is it possible with Entity Framework to (de)serialize an object property from/to to string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm going to create some tables with `Entity Framework` and the code-first approach. However some of my classes have complex properties like:

```
public class Car
{
    public ComplexDate DateBought { get; set; }
}
```

where `ComplexDate` is:

```
public class ComplexDate
{
    public int? Year { get; set; } // Notice the optional Year.
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

and can parse values like `27AUG` or `27AUG15`

Can I somehow configure my `Car` or `ComplexDate` so that I can serialize it into a `string` or deserialize back from a `string`? I'd like to have a column in the database called `DateBought` but in code I wish I could use the `ComplexDate` type for it and be able to parse the value stored in the database.#

IMPORTANT:

I have a few other complex properties that are not dates but are *parsable* that I'd like to store as strings as well and not in still more tables/column. It would overnomalize the database. I think I don't need it.

---

UPDATE:

Here's another example of what I mean:

```
public class Car
{
    public CarColor Color { get; set; }
}


public class CarColor
{
    private string _value;

    // ...more code (ctr, parse etc.)

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to have a `Car`-table with a column named `Color` that would automatically (by some magic) turn into `CarColor` in code... Is there a way? Making the `Color` property (and others) a `string` breaks the whole design of my application because each an every property is a complex type because it has some logic for parsing, allowed values etc. I'd like it to be consistent (everything is complex type) instead of mixing string and classes and other types.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @Arash: I gave up and created a different model for the database and a converter that translates objects from one model to the other. It was way to much work and would make my models unnecessary complicated only to make EF work. So now I have separate models for the database and different models for the application.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you probably want the EF property to be DateTime and just do the conversion in the UI. That way you can bind to a proper database date column and be able to do all the sorting and querying that would be impossible if use your approach.

Comment: The reason why I cannot use the _normal_ `DateTime` is that the `Year` is optional. See the `int?` next to `Year`. I'll try to make it more clear in my question. I have also other complex properties that are not dates.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the date fields individually.

One for Year (nullable), one for Month, one for Day.

That way, you can still sort, group etc. from the database, and use the values in your class to combine and display as you wish.

Comment: It's not only a special date class... I have some other complex properties too. I don't want to split them into 80 columns ;]

Comment: Hi t3chb0t, it would be some design that had 80 things in it stored as a single item in a database table. Storage and manipulation are two separate things. Store the data that you need to store, then have (NotMapped) properties that manipulate the data in the way you wish to display it to the client. Marking them as NotMapped prevents EF from creating columns for the items in the database. EF is smart enough to create the tables, data types, and relationships from the classes that you supply in your model, just mark what you want to not be included by EF.